# pandas melt data with many id_vars into on column

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to melt a DataFrame without using any loops. Suppose I have a DataFrame looking something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'var1': [1,2,3,4,5]*100,
                   'var2': [1,2,3,4,5]*100,
                   'col1': ['a','b']*250,
                   'col2': ['c','d']*250,})


     var1  var2 col1 col2
0       1     1    a    c
1       2     2    b    d
2       3     3    a    c
3       4     4    b    d
4       5     5    a    c
..    ...   ...  ...  ...
495     1     1    b    d
496     2     2    a    c
497     3     3    b    d
498     4     4    a    c
499     5     5    b    d
```

And now I want to melt the data:

```
df.melt(value_vars=['var1', 'var2'], var_name='var', id_vars=['col1', 'col2'])

    col1 col2   var  value
0      a    c  var1      1
1      b    d  var1      2
2      a    c  var1      3
3      b    d  var1      4
4      a    c  var1      5
..   ...  ...   ...    ...
995    b    d  var2      1
996    a    c  var2      2
997    b    d  var2      3
998    a    c  var2      4
999    b    d  var2      5
```

Is it possible to melt the data without using any loops to one column with id_vars? So it would end up looking something like this:

```
    col var value
0   a   var1    1
1   b   var1    2
2   a   var1    3
3   b   var1    4
4   a   var1    5
5   c   var2    1
6   d   var2    2
7   c   var2    3
8   d   var2    4
9   c   var2    5
..  ..  ....   ..
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`wide_to_long`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html), it create new column by number after `var, col` columns, so if necessary added `var` strings:

```
df1 = (pd.wide_to_long(df.reset_index(), stubnames=['var','col'], i='index', j='new')
         .reset_index(level=1)
         .assign(new = lambda x: 'var' + x['new'].astype(str))
         .reset_index(drop=True)
         )
print (df1) 
      new  var col
0    var1    1   a
1    var1    2   b
2    var1    3   a
3    var1    4   b
4    var1    5   a
..    ...  ...  ..
995  var2    1   d
996  var2    2   c
997  var2    3   d
998  var2    4   c
999  var2    5   d

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Possible a bit hack solution with `melt`:

```
df1 = df.melt(value_vars=['var1', 'var2'], var_name='var', id_vars=['col1', 'col2'])
df2 = df.melt(value_vars=['col1', 'col2'], var_name='var', id_vars=['var1', 'var2'])

df = pd.concat([df1[['var','value']], df2['value'].rename('col')], axis=1)
print (df)
      var  value col
0    var1      1   a
1    var1      2   b
2    var1      3   a
3    var1      4   b
4    var1      5   a
..    ...    ...  ..
995  var2      1   d
996  var2      2   c
997  var2      3   d
998  var2      4   c
999  var2      5   d

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Not possible using the melt only?

Comment: @destinychoice - Added solution, but in my opinion a bit hack ;)

Comment: bit hacky ye, and will only work for this use case, suppose you have a lot of value_vars so the amount of columns aint the same.

Answer (score 0):

One option is with [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.pivot.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
#pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd 
import janitor 

(df
.pivot_longer(
    names_to = ['c', 'var'], 
    values_to = ('col','value'), 
    names_pattern = ('col*', 'var*'))
.drop(columns = 'c')
)
    col   var  value
0     a  var1      1
1     b  var1      2
2     a  var1      3
3     b  var1      4
4     a  var1      5
..   ..   ...    ...
995   d  var2      1
996   c  var2      2
997   d  var2      3
998   c  var2      4
999   d  var2      5

[1000 rows x 3 columns]
```